# What causes the error “unexpected numeric constant” in `data$NA`?

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'm using the [linERR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linERR/linERR.pdf) package in R, and have built a survival object, but I get an error that I cannot dissect the meaning of. Can somebody help me understand what it is pointing at?

The data is split survival data.

**My Code**

```
surv <- with(data, Surv(enter, end, event=event_name, type='interval', origin=0))
fit.1 <- fit.linERR(surv ~ sex | dose4cat, data=data, beta=NULL, ages=attage)
```

**Infernal Error Output**

```
Error in parse(text = paste0(Call$data, "$", lin.part1[i])) : <text>:1:6: unexpected numeric constant
1: data$NA
     ^
```

**My Data Structure**

```
> data
  id period entry      end    event_name
1  1      1      0 0.88820072      1
2  2      1      0 0.05562832      0
3  3      1      0 1.00000000      0
4  3      2      1 2.00000000      0
5  3      3      2 5.24113929      1
6  4      1      0 1.00000000      0
7  4      2      1 2.00000000      0
8  4      3      2 2.91370906      1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your arrow is in the wrong place: you get that error with

```
> parse(text="data$NA")
Error in parse(text = "data$NA") : 
  <text>:1:6: unexpected numeric constant
1: data$NA
         ^
```

So the issue is that `lin.part1[i]` evaluates to `NA`.  You haven't made your example reproducible, so I can't offer any advice on why that happened.